# Problem with text on Ubuntu 14.04 (freenx)

Tags: mate, remmina, freenx

After reconnecting to FreeNX session I don't have any text on display, only windows, panels and not one letter.
I use Ubuntu 14.04, freenx-server, MATE and Remmina with nx-plugin on the client computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to exclude which side causes the issue I would recommend to install

[NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/download)

and play all combinations of old and new clients and servers. Hope it helps.

Also you can try to install qtnx client, it is not in Ubuntu repository, though can be installed, here is [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX#Installing_the_NX_Client)